# Is there way to automatically replace avx512 with avx2?

Tags: gcc, avx512

Following the advice of Linus Torvalds (and cross platform performance), I wish to not use avx512. Is there a flag I can specify to the compiler (both gcc and msvc) such that all avx512 instructions are split into pairs of avx2 instructions if a library I am using tries to use axv512 either from intrinsics or compiler optimiszation?

Comment: Linus suggests not using AVX-512 even on CPUs that have it?  I know he's said AVX-512 is a "power virus" for CPU designers (which makes some sense; adding the nice masking features to 256-bit vectors would have been fine and let more CPUs have it earlier).  Avoiding 512-bit vectors also makes sense, but on a CPU that already spent the transistors / tradeoffs to have it, why would you avoid AVX-512 entirely?  It can sometimes save instructions for 256-bit vectors.  Can you link what you're referring to?  Maybe Linus said AVX-512 in general when he really just meant full-width 512-bit vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, compile your code not to use AVX-512 in the first place by telling the compiler it can't; you only have to do anything about code using intrinsics that require AVX-512.

---

However, if you're compiling for a CPU that supports AVX-512, it's often worth using it, especially with 256-bit vectors to avoid the [turbo-frequency and other penalties that come with 512-bit vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852812/simd-instructions-lowering-cpu-frequency).  **GCC's default tuning is already `-mprefer-vector-width=256`** for CPUs like `-march=skylake-avx512`.

If you want to make a binary that can run on CPUs without AVX-512, then yes obviously you need to make sure it never executes and instructions that would fault without it.  e.g. `gcc -O3 -march=znver2` or `-march=skylake` or whatever.  Neither of those target arch options include AVX-512. Or `-march=native` if compiling for whatever CPU you have.

But if you do have a CPU that supports AVX-512, and you want to not use it, you can use something like **`-march=native -mno-avx512f`**  (All other AVX-512 extensions depend on the "Foundation" AVX-512F, so disabling that also prevents even AVX-512VL for 128 and 256-bit vectors.)

(Part of the benefit of `-march=native` and then disabling stuff is to also set tuning options.  If you want a binary that runs well on both Skylake and Zen2, I'm not sure what to recommend; probably `-march=skylake` or `-march=znver2` are both ok; there's the default "tune=generic" but it cares too much about really old CPUs that don't even support AVX2, like Sandybridge: [Why doesn't gcc resolve _mm256_loadu_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626726/why-doesnt-gcc-resolve-mm256-loadu-pd-as-single-vmovupd))

---

### Intrinsics

Even with intrinsics, GCC will only ever emit instructions supported by the target options, so `-mno-avx512f` can let you be sure you didn't miss anything.  You'll get compile time errors, instead of EVEX instructions slipping through the cracks.

(MSVC is different and is designed around a single-binary model where using new instruction-sets is done in functions that you only call if the CPU supports it, so it won't stop you from using AVX-512.  AFAIK, MSVC still doesn't even have an option to auto-vectorize with AVX-512, only `/arch:AVX2`.  But anyway, MSVC won't emit AVX-512 instructions on its own if you don't tell it to, if you don't use any option like `/arch:AVX512` if such a thing exists; AFAIK it doesn't have a `/arch:native` unfortunately.  With MSVC you do have to be sure you caught all uses of intrinsics, although compiling with GCC can help to make sure your codebase doesn't do that.)

If you still want to compile code that uses `_mm512_add_epi32` or `_mm256_ternlog_epi32` or whatever, you'll need a version of immintrin.h that defines `__m512i` as a struct/class with two `__m256i` members and emulates all the intrinsics. **Some AVX512 intrinsics won't be cheap to emulate, especially masked operations,** and the whole concept of compare-into-mask to get an integer instead of a vector.  So it's probably a bad idea to try to make this happen fully transparently; instead just get GCC to stop you from using any AVX-512 instructions while you make AVX2-only versions of any intrinsics code that didn't already have AVX2 versions.

Last time this came up, [Coding on insufficient hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637886/coding-on-insufficient-hardware/53644322#53644322), I was able to find an `avxintrin-emu.h` that let you develop for AVX while only compiling for SSE4.  But I didn't find an equivalent for AVX-512.  (Normally you would compile an AVX-512 binary and test it on an emulator like SDE that emulates at runtime, not compile-time.)

Agner Fog's VectorClass wrapper library (https://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) has support for basic operations like + - * /, and shuffles and blends, and has versions 512-bit vectors emulated with a pair of AVX2 vectors.  (And VCL types are implicitly convertible to __m256i or __m512i and so on, so for operations it doesn't have its own functions for, you can use Intel intrinsics. But then you're back in the same boat of needing a library that emulates `__m256_ternlog_epi32` with only AVX2 instructions.)

---

This won't stop libc from possibly using hand-written AVX-512 instructions in functions like `strcmp` or `log`/`exp`, since dynamic CPU dispatching happens at run-time, and you can't stop your CPU from reporting that it supports AVX-512.  (Except with a VM, or by telling the kernel not to enable AVX-512 at boot, if Linux has an option for that.)