# Getting Illegal Instruction while running a basic Avx512 code

Tags: c++, x86, avx, instruction-set, avx512

I am trying to learn AVX instructions and while running a basic code I recieve

> Illegal instruction (core dumped)

The code is mentioned below and I am compiling it using

> g++ -mavx512f 1.cpp

What exactly is the problem and how to overcome it?
Thank You!

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void add(const float a[], const float b[], float res[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    for(; i < (n&(~0x31)) ; i+=32 )
    {
        __m512 x = _mm512_loadu_ps( &a[i] );
        __m512 y = _mm512_loadu_ps( &b[i] );

        __m512 z = _mm512_add_ps(x,y);
        _mm512_stream_ps(&res[i],z);
    }

    for(; i<n; i++) res[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

int main()
{
    int n = 100000;
    float a[n], b[n], res[n];
    for(int i = 0;i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = i+10;
    }
    add(a,b,res,n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) cout<<res[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO].   It's hard to help you debug your code if we cannot fully compile it. 
You should add enough code [mcve] so that someone else doesn't have to create other bits to test it.  As it stands it's not going to be worth the time to test your code out.  In this case, can you also ensure that your CPU supports AVX2 and AVX512. :)

Comment: Probably your CPU doesn't support AVX512.  Use `g++ -march=native` to enable everything your CPU supports.  If you get compile errors, your CPU does *not* support AVX512.

Comment: what lets you think you can use this instruction on your CPU?

Comment: @PeterCordes  I get compile errors with it. So, my cpu doesnt support AVX512. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Probably your CPU doesn't support AVX512 at all.**
**Only CPUs of these and newer generations support AVX-512:**

- [Wikipedia has a nice table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512) (including breakdown by which feature, like AVX512VBMI or FP16)
- Zen 4 (and later).
- Server/workstation: [Skylake-SP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)#%22Skylake-SP%22_(14_nm)_Scalable_Performance) ("Xeon Scalable Performance") and later,
  [Skylake-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)#Xeon_High-end_desktop_processors_(Skylake-X)) high-end desktop/workstation.
- Client: [Ice Lake](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/ice_lake_(client)) / Tiger Lake e.g. i5-1035G4, and [Rocket Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Lake) desktop, e.g. i5-11600.
  (Also the very-limited-release [Cannon Lake laptop chip](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/cannon_lake))
  Celeron / Pentium versions of these have AVX2 but not AVX-512<sup>1</sup>.

  Not Alder Lake (12th gen); Intel regressed their AVX-512 support, and are actively blocking people from using the AVX-512 support in the silicon, which was initially usable with the E-cores disabled.

  Intel Client CPUs will eventually be able to once again take advantage of the AVX-512 hardware that exists in their silicon with [AVX10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#AVX10), which allows them to expose the 256-bit vector-width subset of AVX-512 with all the juicy features like masking, `vpternlogd`, better shuffles, 32 vector registers, broadcast memory-source operands, etc.  [Announced in 2023](https://www.theregister.com/2023/08/15/avx10_intel_interviews/), still no word on client CPUs supporting it (which would require them to implement it on E cores).  I'd have thought microcode updates could report AVX10.1/512 support on existing AVX-512 CPUs, since it doesn't add anything new until AVX10.2 (FP rounding-mode overrides in the EVEX prefix for vector widths other than 512-bit), but instead apparently Granite Rapids will be the first to support AVX10.1.
- Xeon Phi compute cards, 2nd gen and later ([Knight's Landing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon_Phi#Knights_Landing)).

---

### Compiler options

**Use clang or  `g++ -O3 -march=native` to enable everything your CPU supports.**

If you get compile errors (like undeclared function `_mm512_loadu_ps`), your CPU does *not* support AVX512 so g++ didn't enable it.  (Or whatever other CPU feature you're trying to use.)

`immintrin.h` would still define the intrinsic, with `__attribute__((always_inline,target("avx512f"))`.  So it's required to inline, but can only do so into functions that are themselves using `__attribute__((target("avx512f"))` or a similar pragma, or command line options.  That's why the error message is about inlining failed for an `always_inline` function (the intrinsic wrapper around the `__builtin_ia32_...`) into a function with incompatible target options.

Only use separate `-mavx512f` and `-mtune=` options if you want to make a binary for other CPUs, not just the machine you're compiling on.  Related:

- [What exactly do the gcc compiler switches (-mavx -mavx2 -mavx512f) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229343/what-exactly-do-the-gcc-compiler-switches-mavx-mavx2-mavx512f-do)
- [The Effect of Architecture When Using SSE / AVX Intrinisics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747789/the-effect-of-architecture-when-using-sse-avx-intrinisics) (MSVC and classic ICC are different: you can use intrinsics without telling the compiler it can use those ISA extensions, so even within one function their optimizer has to be careful with code-motion out of branches.)
- [error: inlining failed to call always_inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654290/error-inlining-failed-to-call-always-inline)

---

**Related: [How to test AVX-512 instructions w/o supported hardware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805127/how-to-test-avx-512-instructions-w-o-supported-hardware)**

- [Coding on insufficient hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637886/coding-on-insufficient-hardware)
- [Intel AVX intrinsics: any compatibility library out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708501/intel-avx-intrinsics-any-compatibility-library-out) (emulate at compile time instead of runtime).

MSVC and ICC *do* let you use intrinsics without telling the compiler the target supports them, so this method of checking your code against the CPU doesn't work with those compilers.  They'll happily let you compile code that won't run on the current CPU.  (Because MSVC assumes you're going to do runtime CPU detection and dispatching, instead of distributing source code for everyone to optimize for their own machine.)

---

#### More about CPUs without AVX-512

Intel [processor name/number meanings](https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/processors/processor-numbers.html)

Skylake-client does *not* have AVX-512, only Skylake-server.
Intel [Alder Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alder_Lake_(microprocessor)) hybrid (big.LITTLE) CPUs [won't have AVX-512](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/intel-alder-lake-specifications-price-benchmarks-release-date), only AVX2 even on the big cores.
Low-power CPUs like Silvermont / Tremont don't even have AVX1, until Gracemont (Alder Lake E-cores).

Also note, there are multiple extensions to AVX-512, like AVX-512VPOPCNTDQ that introduces SIMD instructions to count set bits in each SIMD element. Check **Wikipedia's [CPUs with AVX-512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512) table** to see which CPU has what.  AVX-512F is the "foundation", and AVX-512VL allows using cool new instructions on 128 and 256-bit vectors.

Footnote 1: Pentium/Celeron versions of older Intel CPUs don't even have AVX, just SSE4.2. (Also lacking BMI1/2 because they disabled decoding of VEX prefixes).

Comment: Zen4 has been released, and does indeed have AVX-512.