# Illegal Instruction with mm_cmpeq_epi8_mask

Tags: gcc, intrinsics, instruction-set, compiler-flags, avx512

Im trying to run code similar to the following

```
#include <immintrin.h>
void foo() {
    __m128i a = _mm_set_epi8 (0,0,6,5,4,3,2,1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1);
    __m128i b = _mm_set_epi8 (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1);
    __mmask16 m = _mm_cmpeq_epi8_mask(a,b); // supposedly requires avx512vl and avx512bw
    std::cout<<m<<std::endl;
}
void bar() {
    int dataa[8] = {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0};
    __m256i points = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i *)&dataa[0]); // requires just mavx
    (void)points;
}
```

However, I keep running into the error `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`

I compile the code with

> g++ -std=c++11 -march=broadwell -mavx -mavx512vl -mavx512bw  tests.cpp

According to Intel's intrinsics documentation, these flags should be sufficient to run both `foo` and `bar`. However, when either `foo` or `bar` is run, I get the same error message.

If I remove `foo`, however, and compile WITHOUT `-mavx512vl`, I can run `bar` smoothly.

I already checked that my cpu supports the `mno-avx512vl` and `mno-avx512bw` flags so it should support `mavx512vl` and `mavx512bw` right?

What flags must I include to run both functions?  Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Compile with `gcc -march=native`**.  If you get compile errors, your source tried to use something your CPU doesn't support.

**Related: [Getting Illegal Instruction while running a basic Avx512 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621809/getting-illegal-instruction-while-running-a-basic-avx512-code/56621952#56621952)**

---

> I already checked that my cpu supports the mno-avx512vl and mno-avx512bw flags so it should support mavx512vl and mavx512bw right?

That's the opposite of how GCC options work.

**`-mno-avx512vl` *disables* `-mavx512vl`** if any earlier option (like `-march=skylake-avx512` or `-mavx512vl` on its own) had set it.

`-march=broadwell` doesn't enable AVX512 instructions because Broadwell CPUs can't run them natively.  So `-mno-avx512vl` has exactly zero effect at the end of `g++ -std=c++11 -march=broadwell -mavx ...`

> Many options have long names starting with ‘-f’ or with ‘-W’—for example, -fmove-loop-invariants, -Wformat and so on. **Most of these have both positive and negative forms; the negative form of -ffoo is -fno-foo.** This manual documents only one of these two forms, whichever one is not the default.
>
> from the GCC manual, intro part of [section 3: Invoking GCC 3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)

(`-m` options follow the same convention as `-f` and `-W` long options.)

This style of `foo` vs. `no-foo` is not unique to GCC; it's pretty common.

---

**Faulting on `_mm256_lddqu_si256` after compiling with `-mavx512vl`**

GCC is dumb and uses an EVEX encoding for the load (probably `vmovdqu64`) instead of a shorter VEX encoding.  But you told it AVX512VL was available, so this is only an optimization problem, not correctness.

If you did compile the function with only AVX enabled, it would of course only use AVX instructions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid your method to determine the CPU capabilities is not 
very reliable. The fact that your gcc compiler supports AVX-512 doesn't imply
that your CPU supports AVX-512.

On the Linux command line type `more /proc/cpuinfo` and check the flags 
section to see which instruction sets are supported by your CPU.

On windows: 1. Open settings, 2. Click on System, 3. Click on About.
This will show you the processor type. Google
`intel ark 'processor type'` for example Google `intel ark core i3 7100`.
Then follow the link to the [processor page on the Intel website](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97455/intel-core-i3-7100-processor-3m-cache-3-90-ghz.html) and check the *Advanced Technologies* 
-> *Instruction Set Extensions* item.

There are many levels of AVX-512 support. AVX-512_BW AVX-512_VL are standard on processors with AVX-512 support, unless you are working with a Knights Landing or Mill processor. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512 or https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/x86/avx-512#Implementation.

Answer (score 2):

For Intel's ISAs the general rule is that the latter architecture is a superset of the former. As AVX512 is the latest of the ones you mentioned you don't have to use **-mavx**. Using of **-march=broadwell** is useless as you cannot optimize for a CPU that doesn't have AVX512 ISA.

Your command line should look like

```
g++ -std=c++11 -march=skylake-avx512 tests.cpp
```

Also, the statement "my CPU supports those compiler flags" is odd. I presume you mean "the code I built with those flags runs on my CPU" but as it was already mentioned **no** prefix means do **NOT** generate code for such an ISA.

So, your compiler flags are fine it is the CPU you have doesn't have support for the required ISA.

Comment: `-march=broadwell` is never useless, you should prefer using a `-march` option to set tuning options (`-mtune=broadwell`) *and* enable other instruction set extensions like popcnt, BMI1/BMI2, CMPXCHG16B, and other non-SIMD extensions that the compiler might take advantage of.  There are very few reasons to use `-mavx512bw` instead of `-march=skylake-avx512`.  It also would have avoided this mistake because the OP knows they don't have a Skylake-X CPU.  Other than that, good answer.

Comment: OK, there are two scenarios: either `-march=broadwell` wins and there are no AVX512 instructions or `-mavx512*` wins and AVX512 instructions get generated. In the first case the OP doesn't have the desired instruction emitted. In the second case gcc would be optimizing for a chip that doesn't actually exists. I have to correct myself the option is not useless but using it can lead to unexpected consequences performance-wise.

Comment: @PeterCordes But of course the approach of using an appropriate `-march` instead of number of -m's is the preferred one. So, yes, `-march=skylake-avx512` is pretty much sufficient for what OP is doing.

Comment: In this specific case, tune=broadwell is better than tune=generic for every existing CPU that supports AVX512BW + AVX512VL.  Because [currently those are all Skylake-server derived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512), and tune=skylake-avx512 is pretty close to tune=broadwell, and rules out tuning for any AMD CPUs.

Comment: And no, it's not a matter of `-march=broadwell` "winning" vs. `-mavx512vl`.  They're additive.  `-march=broadwell` enables basically every Intel extension before AVX512, and `-mavx512vl` enables AVX512F + AVX512VL.  Only if you'd used `-mno-avx2` or something would it matter which one was last. There are still so few AVX512 CPUs that it doesn't make sense to recommend tune=generic for compiling any AVX512 code; always use either `-march=skylake-avx512` or `-march=knl` (or `knm`).  So you should edit your answer to not recommend using `-mavx512vl -mavx512bw` by themselves; that's silly.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, you are right about `-march=skylake-avx512` being better than passing specific ISA extensions. I fixed the answer. Thanks!  

The "winning" thing was indeed uncalled for because even though some compilers would do "right most flag wins" thing but since this is gcc in question such a concern is irrelevant.  

I overlooked the fact that `-m` by itself defaults to `-tune=generic -march=x86-64` (at least on 64-bit OS) and, of course, tuning for broadwell makes it definitely closer to any actual AVX512-enabled chip than tuning for generic.